# What's the mean of the rotation vector which got from solvePnP in opencv?

Tags: opencv, rotational-matrices

I want use the function `solvepnp`to compute the Euler angle,and I got `rvec` .It's the rotation vector.what is it mean？

Using `Rodrigues()` can get the rotation matrix.How can I get the the pitch,yaw,and roll directly from `rvec`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Euler_AxisAngle.png) illustrates the rotation vector representation: the vector part represents a direction and the angle part is the amount on which you want to rotate around the vector/direction:
[image: By DF Malan (Own work) [Public domain], via Wikimedia Commons]
By DF Malan (Own work) [Public domain], via Wikimedia Commons

First, you have to keep in mind that there is a loss of freedom with Euler angles representation that could lead to [gimbal lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock). This is not the case with rotation matrix or rotation vector representation.

Then, you have to choose a convention (z-y-x, x-y-z, ...) for [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles).

Finally, based on the rotation order you have chosen, you have to extract the Euler angles from the rotation matrix, [here](http://www.staff.city.ac.uk/~sbbh653/publications/euler.pdf) you have the corresponding equations for a specific convention. You will see that some rotation matrix forms will produce ambiguities (multiple or infinite possible values for some part of the Euler angles).

[Here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/3.1.0/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/calib3d/real_time_pose_estimation/src/Utils.cpp#L189) you can find the conversion rotation matrix to Euler angles for the convention the author have chosen in OpenCV ([here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/d2c/tutorial_real_time_pose.html) the tutorial from which the code comes from).

Comment: thank you. some of these links are not working. Is it possible to convert Quaternions to rotation vector?

Comment: @Mr.RandyTom Yes, to convert Quaternion to rotation vector (or angle axis representation) you can have a look at [this page](https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/quaternionToAngle/) or use the Eigen library to perform the conversion, see [the documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1AngleAxis.html).